# Use a variable to push json

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I want push some Data into a predefined JSON variable using a variable.
Here are my predefined JSON variables:

```
    data(){
        return {
            dataMON: [],
            dataTUE: [],
            dataWED: [],
            dataTHU: [],
            dataFRI: []

        }
    }
```

And this is the Stuff I want to push:

```
getTimeTable() {
                var db = firebase.firestore();

                var date = new Date();
                var weekday = new Array(5);
                weekday[0] = "monday";
                weekday[1] = "tuesday";
                weekday[2] = "wednesday";
                weekday[3] = "thursday";
                weekday[4] = "friday";

                weekday.forEach(day => {

                    var dayLowerCase = day.slice(0, 3);
                    var dayUpperCase = dayLowerCase.toUpperCase();


                    var tmpTable = {
                        period: doc.id,
                        course: fullTempTable.fach,
                        teacher: fullTempTable.lehrer,
                        room: fullTempTable.raum
                                };
                                this.day.[dayUpperCase].push(tmpTable);   

                });
            }
```

The problem is that I cant use day[dayUpperCase] since that would try to find the Object dayUpperCase. Can you even use variable in this case?

Comment: [There's no JSON anywhere in your question, just JavaScript](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to construct the *whole* property name in your string.

```
var dayUpperCase = dayLowerCase.toUpperCase();
var propertyName = "day" + dayUpperCase;
```

Then you can access it with bracket notation (which doesn't use a `.` in front):

```
this[propertyName]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better practice to create another object:

```
data() {
    return {
        day: {
            MON: [],
            TUE: [],
            WED: [],
            THU: [],
            FRI: []
        }
    };
}
```

This is cleaner than adding strings in the long run, since it will keep your `data` object organized. Having to add strings to create property names is a bit of a "[code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)" for when you should just create another object. For example, if a future developer saw the `data` object, they might `ctrl-f` for "dataMON" to see where it's being accessed/set, but because the properties are constructed, this won't work. Similarly, lots of IDEs will let you "Find all usages" of a given property; that also won't work because of the dynamic properties. Using a separate object will let other developers find where the `.day` object is modified/accessed easier.

You can then write (note that we don't need a `.` when using `[]`):

```
this.day[dayUpperCase].push(tmpTable);
```

Comment: Yeah, I guess that could also work. But @Quentins solution was better for my situation. Thanks anyways.

Comment: (updated answer) I don't know the specifics of your project, but having to add strings to create property names is a "code smell" for when you should just create another object. This solution would probably be considered better practice based on the code you've shown. But no worries, whatever works best for you :)